# Trying to stop randomly generated pic boxes to not intersect with each other

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a program in windows forms that generate random coordinate points to draw fish. I need the fish to stop intersecting with each other but the code I wrote doesn't work. The coordinates generated should be put into rectangles and then checked against all the other points rectangles. The fish keep intersecting. Any idea why?
[Code I wrote to stop the intersection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIGc.png)

```
for (int i = 0; i < fishNumber; i++)
{
    // Checks for overlapping
    fishX = x.Next(200, 3100);
    fishY = y.Next(100, 1620);

    fishPoints.Add(new Point(fishX, fishY));
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        while (i != 0 && new Rectangle(fishPoints[i], new Size(200, 134)).IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(fishPoints[j], new Size(200, 134))))
        {
            fishPoints.RemoveAt(i);
            fishX = x.Next(200, 3100);
            fishY = y.Next(100, 1620);
            fishPoints.Add(new Point(fishX, fishY));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just added it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like the below out.  It only adds the point AFTER it has been determined that it doesn't intersect with any of the other fish:

```
Size fishSize = new Size(200, 134);
for (int i = 0; i < fishNumber;i++)
{
    Point pt;
    bool collided;
    do
    {
        collided = false;
        pt = new Point(x.Next(200, 3100), y.Next(100, 1620));
        Rectangle rcNewFish = new Rectangle(pt, fishSize);
        foreach(Point otherPt in fishPoints)
        {
            if (rcNewFish.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(otherPt, fishSize)))
            {
                collided = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (collided);
    fishPoints.Add(pt);
}
```